# can i use the PromptDialog.choice continuously to ask many related infomation in botframework

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to ask many questions continuously to user, and each question depends on the choose of the question before. I want to use  PromptDialog.Choice() to  implement it but i find if i do it like this, since the second user info, will still invoke the first callback function, and i don't know how to jump out from the function.

```
public void getchoose(IDialogContext context)
   {

       List<string> option_provide = null;
       bool if_find = true;
       foreach (var i in question.GetSortedProperties())
       {
           nowchoice = i;

           if (!question.select<test_tableinfo>(i.Name, (string)i.GetValue(question), allOptions, out allOptions, out option_provide))
           {

               if (allOptions.Count() == 1)
               {
                   context.PostAsync(allOptions.First().answer);

                   if_find = false;
                   context.Wait(MessageReceived);
               }

               if (option_provide.Count() < 1)
               {

                   context.PostAsync("请联系客服");
                   if_find = false;
               }
               else if (option_provide.Count() == 1)
               {
                   i.SetValue(question, option_provide[0]);
                   question.select(i.Name, (string)i.GetValue(question), allOptions, out allOptions, out option_provide);
               }
               else
               { 
                   PromptDialog.Choice<string>(context, AfterChoose, option_provide, "选择你需要的"+i.Name, "retry", 2);
                   if_find = false;
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
       if (if_find)
       {
           foreach (var i in allOptions)
           {
               context.PostAsync(i.answer);
           }
           context.Wait(MessageReceived);
       }

   }
```

and the callback function afterchoose

```
 public async Task AfterChoose(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> choice)
   {      
       try
       {
           string temp = await choice;
           if (temp != null)
               nowchoice.SetValue(question, temp);

       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
       }
       context.Reset();
       getchoose(context);            
   }
```

i use reflection here to get the order of variables but it is not important for this question

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is already part of the Bot Framework.  FormFlow is a feature that allows you to construct a model of the data that you wish to gather from the user and then ask a series of questions, which can be branched in necessary depending upon answers.

Check out the [FormFlow documentation on the Bot Framework site](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html).